# Powershell script to delete multiple user profile on multiple server

Tags: windows, powershell, script

Showing error that "`remove-localUser`" is not recognised as the name of cmdlet....

```
$hostdetail = Import-CSV C:\Users\jj\Desktop\Test\hosts.csv

ForEach ($item in $hostdetail)
{
$hostname = $($item.hostname)
$username = $($item.username)
$computer = $hostname

#Test network connection and Windows version on the remote desktop

If ((!(Test-Connection -comp $computer -count 1 -quiet)) -Or ((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer Win32_OperatingSystem -ea stop).Version -lt 6.0))
{
Write-Warning "$computer is not accessible or The Operating System of the $computer is not supported.`nClient: Vista and above`nServer: Windows 2008 and above."
}
else
{
$User = $username
$SB = {
Remove-LocalUser -InputObject $Using:User
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock $SB
}
}
```

Comment: I am using powershell 5.1 version

Comment: "The Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts module is not available in 32-bit PowerShell on a 64-bit system." Are you running 32 bit powershell?

Comment: How can I find it? But I know this that I am using 64-bit system.

Comment: Can you please suggest me the alternative code to run this script instead of removelocaluser

Comment: `[System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess` in your powershell windows

Comment: I got the answer as true

Comment: Is there any other way to delete multiple user on remote server through powershell?

Comment: Actually I don't have a permission to download anything on that server.

Comment: What OS? Have you considered `net user`?

Comment: what is the version of PoSh on the remote system? that error msg is quite specific ... the system was not able to find that specific cmdlet. the most common reason is that the remote system has a version of PoSh that does not include the   `*-LocalUser` cmdlets. i _think_ those were added in v5.0 ... but the MSDocs do not show that detail. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989815/cant-find-microsoft-powershell-localaccounts-module-or-run-get-localuser, "This cmdlet was made available with Server 2016 and Win10 1607+. On earlier OS's, you will either need to use net.exe, WMI, ADSI, or a module that uses one of those methods or install WMF 5.1."

Comment: Can anyone please tell me one line that will use instead of using Remove-LocalUser line? Is there any alternative for this.. please write a code for that.. thanks in advance..

Comment: @Catherine - please take a look at the `net.exe` command & the `user` parameter as suggested by user9938.

Comment: How can I use net.exe? I don't have enough knowledge of powershell..

Comment: Your Windows 10 has a 32-bit PowerShell and 64-bit PowerShell prompt.  The solution to your problem is simply make sure you are launching a 64-bit instance of PowerShell instead of launching a 32-bit instance.  It's unlikely you will be able to find a one line alternative given your limited permissions on the server itself.  If you are having trouble launching the correct instance, use the full path, to the correct executable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete Local Accounts with Powershell Script](https://superuser.com/questions/1569479/delete-local-accounts-with-powershell-script)

Comment: How about this function: [Remove Multiple User Profiles of a Remote Machine](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4908-delete-remote-user-profile)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to delete local accounts on remote machines without installing new powershell modules is via the ADSI WinNT Provider, since it works on all NT versions of windows:

```
$ADSI = [ADSI]"WinNT://$hostname"
$ADSI.Delete('User',$username)
```

Comment: @pillsbury, I am having a task to delete users from vm. details of users and vm should be in the excel file and script will take one server and delete all users mentioned corresponding to that vm and then next server and so on

Comment: @pillsbury, can you please help me how to read data of excel which means script read one computer name and then delete all users from that machine and then take another and delete all users from that vm which is mentioned in excel.

Answer (score 0):

I've integrated some PowerShell logic below for you  which I've been able to use successfully against remote Windows 10 machines removing specific profiles and such just fine many times.

I'm going to assume you have no issue with `PS-Remoting` against your remote systems and you are executing this logic while logged on as a credential that has remote PS access and local admin privileges.

> **A couple differences here compared to what you were using is...**
>
> 1. This uses `Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile` along with `Remove-CimInstance` rather than `Remove-LocalUser -InputObject`
> 2. With `Invoke-Command` this uses the `-AsJob` parameter to execute the command on the remote system as a background job, and then move on
>    doing the same for each subsequent server in the list.

### PowerShell

```
$hostdetail = Import-Csv "C:\Users\jj\Desktop\Test\hosts.csv";

$hostdetail | % {
    $usename = $_.username;
    $computer = $_.hostname;
    #Test network connection and Windows version on the remote desktop
    If ((!(Test-Connection -comp $computer -count 1 -quiet)) -or 
       ((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer Win32_OperatingSystem -ea stop).Version -lt 6.0))
    {
        Write-Warning "$computer is not accessible or The Operating System of the $computer is not supported.`nClient: Vista and above`nServer: Windows 2008 and above.";
    }
    Else
    {
        $User = $username;
        $SB = { Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile | ? { $_.LocalPath.split("\")[-1] -eq "$Using:User" } | Remove-CimInstance };
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock $SB -AsJob;
    }
    };
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-CIMInstance](https://ss64.com/ps/get-ciminstance.html)
- [Remove-CIMInstance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/remove-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.1)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Where-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)

  > The '`?`' symbol and Where are both aliases for Where-Object. If you